# Tag "lock" is a mess

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The tag [lock](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lock) seems to be a mess.

It's used for among other things:

- [file locks](https://superuser.com/questions/435021/windows-7-locking-process-files-folders)
- [lock screen](https://superuser.com/questions/423877/no-matter-what-i-do-my-laptop-windows-7-keeps-going-to-the-lock-screen)
- [keyboard lock](https://superuser.com/questions/423948/disabling-modifier-lock-with-the-fn-key-on-a-packard-bell-easynote)
- [locking of preferences](https://superuser.com/questions/421380/lock-universal-access-preferences)
- [excel](https://superuser.com/questions/157562/excel-lock-sheet-but-keep-tables-expandable)

We should do something about it. 
We should probably make new tags for the first two perhaps [file-lock](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-lock) and [lock-screen](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lock-screen).

Comment: How many questions can be asked about the lock screen, really? Locked files -- maybe. But other than that, it looks pretty useless.

Comment: Also, [Kensington locks](http://superuser.com/questions/246234/how-can-i-make-it-difficult-to-install-a-new-operating-system-on-a-certain-compu).

Comment: *Lock, lock, lock, lock, Excel*. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]